# Custom JS logic to validate IP ranges does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, typescript, ip-address

I need to create some logic that allows for validation of a specified IP range. Not a single IP address but two addresses that make up a single range.

I thought this would be somewhat simple so I devised some JS code that splits up the two input strings represented the ranges using a `.` delimiter and then compared each number in the first range with the equivalent number in the second range. If the start number is greater than the end number then the range would be invalid.

This works, to a degree. However it's not completely accurate as I'm getting pairs such as `127.0.0.3 / 128.0.0.1` which return false when in reality this pair of IP addresses is a valid range (ignoring the technicalities with using 127 etc.)

I'm not sure how exactly to check for a valid IP range, using Google doesn't seem to return any information on how to validate an IP range either.

How can I change my code around so that all invalid ranges are included and all invalid are excluded?

```
getIpRangeValidStates() : boolean[] {
    console.log("getIdRangeValidStates");
    let validStates = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.ipRangeFormArray.length; i++){
      let currentFormGroup = this.ipRangeFormArray.controls[i];
      let startRangeElements = (currentFormGroup.get('startRange').value as string).split(".");
      let endRangeElements = (currentFormGroup.get('endRange').value as string).split(".");

      let rangeValid = true;
      for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        let startRangeAsInt = parseInt(startRangeElements[j]);
        let endRangeAsInt = parseInt(endRangeElements[j]);
        console.log(startRangeAsInt, " : ", endRangeAsInt);

        if(isNaN(startRangeAsInt) || isNaN(endRangeAsInt))
        {
          console.log("NaN, invalid");
          rangeValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
          if(startRangeAsInt > endRangeAsInt) {
            console.log(startRangeAsInt, " > ", endRangeAsInt, "- invalid")
            rangeValid = false;
          }
        }
      }

      rangeValid === false ? validStates.push(false) : validStates.push(true); 
    }
    console.log("Range states: ", validStates);
    return validStates;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I split your code in two loops: one that checks if the single elements are valid and one that validates the ranges.
Note that as soon as one of the elements in the first range is larger than its counterpart in the second range we can say that the range is invalid: there is no need to check further. Conversely, if the element in the first range is smaller that the element in the second range then the range is valid. There is really no need to check further unless the elements in both ranges are equal.

```js
getIpRangeValidStates() : boolean[] {
  console.log("getIdRangeValidStates");
  let validStates = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < this.ipRangeFormArray.length; i++){
    let currentFormGroup = this.ipRangeFormArray.controls[i];
    let startRangeElements = (currentFormGroup.get('startRange').value as string).split(".");
    let endRangeElements = (currentFormGroup.get('endRange').value as string).split(".");

    let rangeValid = true;
    for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      let startRangeAsInt = parseInt(startRangeElements[j]);
      let endRangeAsInt = parseInt(endRangeElements[j]);
      console.log(startRangeAsInt, " : ", endRangeAsInt);

      if(isNaN(startRangeAsInt) || isNaN(endRangeAsInt))
      {
        console.log("NaN, invalid");
        rangeValid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (rangeValid) {
      for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        let startRangeAsInt = parseInt(startRangeElements[j]);
        let endRangeAsInt = parseInt(endRangeElements[j]);

        if(startRangeAsInt > endRangeAsInt) {
          console.log(startRangeAsInt, " > ", endRangeAsInt, "- invalid");
          rangeValid = false;
          break;
        }
        if(startRangeAsInt < endRangeAsInt) {
          console.log(startRangeAsInt, " < ", endRangeAsInt, "- valid");
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    rangeValid === false ? validStates.push(false) : validStates.push(true); 
  }
  console.log("Range states: ", validStates);
  return validStates;
}
```

Of course, this can be simplified, but it will give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

When working with IPs i would recommend converting the IP to a number instead of using the string representation.
(An IP String is just a nice human-readable 4 byte integer, each block denoting the value of the byte at that position)

Once you have the ip in number form, checking if an ip comes after another is a simple `<`.
Also checking if an ip is within a certain range `start, end` is trivial:
`ip >= start && ip <= end`.

Code Example to convert the ip string into an integer and comparing it:

```js
function ipToNumber(ipStr) {
  let [a, b, c, d] = ipStr.split('.').map(Number);
  // Note: Normally you would use shifts (a << 24), etc...
  // but javascript only supports *signed* 32bit shifts, so we need to use this.
  return (a * 2**24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + d;
}

let start = ipToNumber("127.0.0.1");
let end = ipToNumber("128.0.0.1");

console.log("Start: ", start.toString(16)); // 0x7f000001
console.log("End: ", end.toString(16)); // 0x80000001
console.log(start > end, start < end); // false, true

// check if ip is in range
let sample1 = ipToNumber("127.244.32.1");
console.log("sample1 in range:", sample1 >= start && sample1 <= end); // true

let sample2 = ipToNumber("128.1.0.22");
console.log("sample2 in range:", sample2 >= start && sample2 <= end); // false
```

Integrated in your code example it could look like this:
(Note: my typescript isn't very good, i converted it to javascript)

```
function toIpNumber(ipStr) {
  let parts = ipStr.split('.').map(Number);
  if(parts.length !== 4 || parts.some(e => isNaN(e) || e < 0 || e > 255)) return false;
  let [a,b,c,d] = parts;
  return (a * 2**24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + d;
}

function getIpRangeValidStates() {
    console.log("getIdRangeValidStates");
    let validStates = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.ipRangeFormArray.length; i++){
      let currentFormGroup = this.ipRangeFormArray.controls[i];
      let startRange = toIpNumber(currentFormGroup.get('startRange').value);
      let endRange = toIpNumber(currentFormGroup.get('endRange').value);

      let rangeValid = true;
      if(startRange === false || endRange === false)
        validStates.push(false);
      else
        validStates.push(startRange <= endRange);
    }
    console.log("Range states: ", validStates);
    return validStates;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i Understood your problem.

The best way to check the provided ips are a range is by converting both ip's to a long int and compare the long int's.

Converting to int can be done like

```
const d = dottedDec.split('.');
const longInt = ((((((+d[0])*256)+(+d[1]))*256)+(+d[2]))*256)+(+d[3]);
```

Note: this code is not checking if its a valid ipv4 or not

Now when you have 2 numbers corresponding to 2 ips, you can compare it to check if its a range, also you can find how many ips in the range etc